# Three.js | Generate dynamically a BezierCurve

Tags: javascript, three.js, bezier

I don't find the right syntax to generate dynamically a BezierCurve from an array, I've tried to make a push, but it don't work.

```
var x = [0,10,100,220,100, etc,...];
var y = [10,0,100,200,200, etc,...];
var z = [100,220,10,0,100, etc,...];

var points = [];

for(i=0; i < x.length; i++){ 
   points.push( new THREE.Vector3( x[i], y[i], z[i] ) );
   } 

var curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3( points );

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var curveObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add(curveObject);
```

An idea ?

Comment: [`THREE.CubicBezierCurve3`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Curves/CubicBezierCurve3) does not take an Array, it takes four (4) [`THREE.Vector3`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3).

Comment: Right André, THREE.CubicBezierCurve3 take 4 Three.Vector3 MAXIMUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
var curve = new (Function.bind.apply(THREE.CubicBezierCurve3, [null].concat(points)));
```

or if you target only ES6 compatible browsers spread operator

```
var curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(...points);
```